# How to combine lsof stat and ps to get more info in one line bash command

Tags: bash, awk, ps, lsof

I can use lsof to get top open files stat for processes, as below:

```
$ lsof -n|awk '{print $2}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr | head -n 5
  17955 11945
  10282 2786
   5980 32152
   1920 27803
   1786 32107
```

Now I want to expand the result to like below with one line bash command,

```
$ lsof -n|awk '{print $2}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr | head -n 5 ...
  17955 11945  java
  10282 2786   python
   5980 32152  ruby
   1920 27803  go
   1786 32107  rust
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you use awk to print $1 (the command) and $2 (the PID) in reverse order ($2, $1) this provides most of the information you want in a usable format. The first `sort` and `uniq -c` still work as expected which leaves you with an unsorted list

```
<count> <PID> <command>
```

Now you just need to modify your final `sort -rn ...` to sort only on  `<count>` which is trivial.

You should probably remove the initial line from the output of lsof too.